# Why DB_NAME() can't be used in dynamic statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax-error

When I write a SQL statement like this in SQL Server 2008:

```
exec(N'update '+DB_NAME()+'..sys_bizfiles set idtask=@newID where to_row_guid=@Lrow_guid')
```

it remained that, the `DB_NAME()` has a syntax error.

Is `DB_NAME()` return the `nvarchar()` string of database name ? What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[`EXEC`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) is a limited production and does *not* accept a general expression: *no functions* can be used in this context.

```
{ EXEC | EXECUTE } 
    ( { @string_variable | [ N ]'tsql_string' } [ + ...n ] )
```

That is, EXEC *only* accepts  *variables* and *string literals* - which can be intermixed and concatenated.

`DB_NAME()` is neither of these and thus results in a syntax error within the restricted production.

For instance, the following is valid because it follows the allowed form:

```
declare @name nvarchar(max) = DB_NAME()
exec('select ''' + @name + ''' as db')
```

(As with the original code, `exec('select ''' + DB_NAME() + ''' as db')` is invalid because `DB_NAME()` is neither a variable nor a string literal.)

Answer (score 1):

Use it in this way

```
DECLARE @QUERY nvarchar(500) = N'update '+cast(DB_NAME() as varchar)+'..sys_bizfiles set idtask=@newID where to_row_guid=@Lrow_guid' 
exec @QUERY
```

Cast is not require as "user3127259"

```
DECLARE @QUERY nvarchar(500) = N'update ' + DB_NAME() +'.dbo.sys_bizfiles set idtask=@newID where to_row_guid=@Lrow_guid' 
exec @QUERY
```

Comment: `CAST` the `DB_NAME()`

Comment: exec(N'update '+cast(DB_NAME() as varchar)+'..sys_bizfiles set idtask=@newID where to_row_guid=@Lrow_guid') it still can't work

Comment: `DECLARE @QUERY nvarchar(500) = N'update '+cast(DB_NAME() as varchar)+'..sys_bizfiles set idtask=@newID where to_row_guid=@Lrow_guid'
exec @QUERY `

Comment: when you are firing the above comment query, what error you are seeing there?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to solve this is by using a variable for the db name:

```
DECLARE @databaseName VARCHAR(MAX) = DB_NAME();
```